# some user accounts are locked frequently at my window 2008 AD server

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have a problem in my Windows 2008 Active Directory.

I haven't found this case in Event Viewer and also still can't search Event ID.  The problem is that one Active Directory user is locked frequently in the morning when he opens his computer.  He is using Ubuntu 12 Desktop. The problem is that he can't login to IM or the Windows network to access the fileserver.

I usually unlock his account in AD each time but that is not a solution because I haven't found any related error log ID in the event log.

Comment: Sounds like a cached password which is automatically tried. Not familiar enough with Ubuntu connecting to AD but I have similar with Windows users who entered their password to a share, then later change their password and then when they try to open the share, Windows tries multiple times the old password and lock their account.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any settings where the user may have configured his password statically. It's possible he would have "remembered" his password for any smb shares.